# Is it possible to get the css properties from a given file?

Tags: css, image, photoshop

I was given an `.ai` file (Illustrator) with 2 styled words.

Is it possible for Photoshop or any image software to read the file and provide me with certain properties, such as **font, size, decoration**?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it?

Comment: You want something that opens an `.ai` file, reads certain proprietary Adobe text properties for each instance of text in the file, and converts these properties to the CSS equivalent? Good luck with that :)

Comment: If it's only 2 styled words... then you can just use it as an image

Comment: My work uses a plugin for InDesign that does a very similar thing.. It takes the styles applied within the `.indd` file and converts them to HTML tags. I don't have any more details than that, but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ilustrator: form menu bar Window; type; character got me the phont and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.............................

Try Adobe Dreamweaver or write your own HTML/CSS code, or a mixture of both. You can import things from Illustrator or Photoshop into Dreamweaver and create HTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Fireworks has a Mobile Extension package for CS5, that includes a feature "CSS Properties". http://www.adobe.com/devnet/fireworks/articles/css3-mobile-pack-extracting.html

Most designers I work with use Photoshop. Fireworks can import those psd files, but the file is usually not suitble to extract css properties from. Haven't tried it with .ia files yet. For web design, everyone should use Fireworks, as that's the software that's designed to be used for the web. IA is for print, Ps is for image manipulation, Fw is for the web. There, I said it :).